# Delete items from a table if they are a certain amount of time old

Tags: sql, sql-server, batch-file

I want to delete items from a table in a database. I have a column called "TimeStamp", that records the date that it was input. I want to create a batch file that will delete anything, that is older than 4 months from the date it was created.

Any suggestions? I am looking for something like this:

```
Delete from RFS_PrintRequests
WHERE TimeStamp = GETDATE < "4 months" AND Version != "eccsn";
```

Comment: Datediff is likely what you want to use. But beware that many may have different interpretations of (today - 4 months) - especially if you need a precise boundary condition. If today were Feb 29 (notice - leap year) what would the 4 month boundary be? Would it be Nov 1 or 160 days prior to Feb 29?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are looking to delete all records older than 4 months from today, you can use the following statement:

```
Delete from RFS_PrintRequests
WHERE TimeStamp <= DATEADD(m,-4,GETDATE()) AND Version != "eccsn";
```

*Note: This dateadd function is going to subtract exactly 4 months from your date, not 120 days*

Comment: Thank you , i was playing with the DATEADD and you just layed it out for me.